# Remove :focus with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input field. When a user focuses on this field, the background of this field will change.

I have a link on my page, too. I want to remove `:focus` when the mouse hovers on this link and the user is on that input field.

I use `removeClass(':focus')` but this code does not work!

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
<a href="#" id="link">Sample Link</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').hover(function (){
        $('form input[name=email]').removeClass(':focus');        
    }, function (){
        $('form input[name=email]').addClass(':focus');        
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
form input[name=email]:focus {
    background-color: yellow;    
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbC2u/) for the above

What should I do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use the in-built [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) methods:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').hover(function (){
        $('form input[name=email]').blur();
    }, function (){
        $('form input[name=email]').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Incredibly, this method does not work at all on Android 2.3, links remain with their hover color. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Andrew Are you using the `hover` event? You'll need to use `touchstart` instead as mobile devices won't have a hover state by default

Comment: Checking this out in 2018 and this still works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#link').hover(function (){
     $("input").blur(); 
 }, function (){
      //mouse leave  
});
});
```

**[Working FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbC2u/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').hover(function (){
        $('form input[name=email]').blur();  
        $('form input[name=email]').css("background-color","");     
    }, function (){
        $('form input[name=email]').focus(); 
        $('form input[name=email]').css("background-color"," yellow");       
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is wrong. It wouldn't take 30 seconds to test this in OP's fiddle

Comment: `focusout` and you know because you wrote a comment. Why not take 30 secs and check?